# How do you findout what class a singleton class belongs to?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose I have `#<Class:A>`(which is the singleton class of `A`) in a variable `var`, I want to do `var.some_function` give `A` as its result, does such a function exist in ruby?
Obviously one way to do this would be `Object.const_get var.to_s.split(':')[1].split('>')[0]` but is there a better way or a existing function in ruby?

Please allow me to clarify my question even further!

```
class A
    class << self
        p self
    end
end
```

gives me  which is the singleton class of A. What I want is

```
class A
    class << self
        p self.some_thing
    end
end
```

to give me A (class A to be precise).

Comment: probably you keeps in mind `self.class` or something similar

Comment: What is returned when you execute `p var`?

Comment: Do you know what `A` will be ahead of time? (I'm assuming no.) Can you provide any more relevant context for how you are creating the singleton class and why you need the original class (and why you can't get it some other way)?

Comment: Yes I can get it another way, like I mentioned in the posted question. I want to know because I want to define a method in a module which I am extending. This method should create instance methods using `self.answer_to_my_question.define_method...` and I am doing this because I want to implement DirtyObjects noob style. :) But all this detail doesn't help my question.

Comment: Somebody tried to do this on a lower level [here](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=7&ArtID=897632).

Answer (score 2):

First off: singleton classes don't belong to classes, they belong to *objects*. (Of course, classes *are* objects.)

The only way to find the object which belongs to a singleton class, is to iterate through every single object in the object memory and check for its singleton class:

```
foo_singleton_class = class << (foo = Object.new); self end

this_is_foo = ObjectSpace.each_object.detect {|obj| 
  begin
    obj.singleton_class == foo_singleton_class
  rescue TypeError => e
    raise unless e.message == "can't define singleton"
  end
}

foo.equal?(this_is_foo)
# => true
```

See also [*Feature #12084 `Class#instance`*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12084) on the Ruby issue tracker, which requests exactly such a method as a feature enhancement in future versions of Ruby.

Comment: Good answer, including the reference to the proposed feature. `foo_singleton_class = (foo = Object.new).singleton_class` may read a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If `var` holds a reference to a singleton class, then you can use `var.superclass` to get the base class.

```
class A
end

obj = A.new
var = obj.singleton_class
#=> #<Class:A>

var.superclass
#=> A
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that and it simply said `Class`!

Comment: Sorry, I answered a little to hastily. Please see my update which will definitely work!

Comment: That will give the singleton class of object as the answer!

Comment: Two things: 1) what version of ruby are you using, 2) are you sure that `var` is holding a reference to the singleton class, or is `var` an object which is based on a singleton class (i.e. you maybe defined some singleton methods on the object that aren't in the original class)?

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity, please re-read it :).

Answer (score 0):

If the class is known to be the singleton class of a module (as opposed, for example, of an instance of a class), you could do this:

```
class A; end
k = A.singleton_class

ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).find { |klass| klass.singleton_class == k }
```

@Jörg's answer is better, however, as it does not restrict the type of object for which the singleton class is given.

Comment: Nice, but `Object.const_get var.to_s.split(':')[1].split('>')[0]` might still be better than iterating through all those objects :).